# Menu fixo responsitivo

Tags: css, menu, layout-responsivo

Tenho um menu fixo que quando visualizado no browser maximizado tudo ocorre perfeitamente porem, quando se diminui a tela, o menu fica fixo e a barra de rolagem não rola ele, é possível resolver isso somente com CSS?

segue meu codigo CSS do menu:

```
{
z-index: 297;
height: 80px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #7F7F7F;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
top: -1px;
border-width: 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na sua folha de estilos:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

onde a `max-width` é o comprimento maximo onde estas regras se aplicam, neste caso o menu acima de 600px já não terá `position: relative;`

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)